# Series convergence or divergence how to test

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, functions, divergent-series

I have the following series defined.

$$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} \cos \left( {\frac{\pi}{2}} k \right) \frac{k}{k+1000}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$$ where $n = 1,2...$

How to test whether this series converges or diverges ?

Comment: Consider enclosing your series in dollar signs, as in `$$ f(x)=x $$` so it will show up as $$ f(x) = x$$

Comment: Are you sure that's not $\cos\bigg(\dfrac\pi2~k\bigg)$ ? As it stands, the series diverges by comparison with the [harmonic series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)). Otherwise, it would converge either by the [Leibniz criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test), or by [Dirichlet's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test).

Comment: Yes. It is `k`. I corrected that typo. Can you please elaborate by answer ?

Comment: At odd values of k the cosine vanishes, while for even values it alternates between 1 and -1. SInce the limit of the rest of the expression tends to zero as k tends to infinity, this series converges by the alternating series test

Answer (score 1):

We have:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\cos\left(\frac{\pi k}{2}\right)\frac{k}{k+1000}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^n \frac{2n+1}{2n+1001}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$$
hence the series is convergent by Leibniz' criterion, since $\frac{2n+1}{2n+1001}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$ decreases towards zero.